# should I have 2 identical tables

Tags: sql, database

I have the need for 2 different types of joins on the same tables (lets say `ADDRESS` and `USER`).  I can either make 2 tables (`BILLING_ADDRESS` and `SHIPPING_ADDRESS`) that both have 3 columns (`ID`, `USER_ID`, `ADDRESS_ID`), or I can make a single table(`CUSTOMER_ADDRESS`) with a type column (`ID`, `USER_ID`, `ADDRESS_ID`, `ADDRESS_TYPE`).

For DRY coding practices I'm thinking just the single table, but that means when I compile the 2 lists I would have to do full table scans twice.

```
select address.* from customer_addresses, address where user_id = 1 and address_type = 'Billing'
```

and

```
select address.* from customer_addresses, address where user_id = 1 and address_type = 'Shipping'
```

Both rely on full table scans of the customer_addresses table.

If we have 1000 customer addresses that means 2000 records have been scanned to find all the addresses for that customer.

If I do the 2 different tables, then only 1000 customer addresses are scanned, because the shipping_addresses table only holds 800 address/customer records, and the billing_addresses table hold the other 200.

So for performance I would have to say the 2 different tables.  For DRY I would have to go with the single table.  What are the industry thoughts on this?

Comment: You're debating the time complexity between 2n and 1n. It hardly matters in this case.

Comment: It shouldn't require a full table scan. An index on `user_id` will filter it down to just 2 rows, then it just has to scan those 2 rows to find the one with the correct `address_type`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A shipping address and a billing address might be different things.  For instance, a billing address might be a PO Box, but a shipping address often cannot be.  Similarly, a shipping address might include other information, such as a contact name, contact phone, and drop-off instructions.  I just mention this because you need to decide whether the differences are material enough to create a separate entity, or just to have a few separate fields in an address table.

This is just to let you know that there might be other fields.

I think this is the query you suggest (with the `join` syntax fixed):

```
select a.*
from customer_addresses ca join
     address a 
     on ca.address_id = a.address_id
where ca.user_id = 1 and ca.address_type = 'Billing';
```

This does not require a full table scan with an intelligent data design.  As Barmar points out in a comment, you should have a proper index on these tables.  In this case, the indexes you want are `customer_address(user_id, address_type)` and `address(address_id)`.  If a database only did full table scans for `SELECT` queries, SQL would be a much less useful language and probably not used anywhere.

Comment: The flexability pointed out by having them in separate tables persuaded me to put them in different tables.

Answer (score 0):

A single table allows for more flexibility. For instance, in the future you might decide to allow a customer to store alternate shipping addresses, and choose one when placing an order. You could then add `address_type = 'Alternate Shipping Address'`, you wouldn't have to add another whole table.

There should be little performance impact of this design. An index on the `user_id` will narrow down the query to just a few rows that need to be scanned for the desired address type.

Answer (score 0):

a single table is much better if it meet all your needs, in this case the both scenarios you mentions will have `redundant data` see the [normalization](http://www.studytonight.com/dbms/database-normalization.php) for more info, in this case I think if you have one table `ADDRESS (ID, USER_ID, SHIPPING_ADDRESS_ID, BILLING_ADDRESS_ID).` is much netter than having tow table for address, in this scenario you can't reach `forth normal form`